# padding on images with a hover effect not matching the same images without the hover effect css

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hover effect on images using css style from https://miketricking.github.io/bootstrap-image-hover/# effect 13, this works but the padding on the text stops working with this setup.

```css
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background: #555;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform: scale(0, 1);
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  filter: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filter"> <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.6" /> <feFuncB type="linear" slope="0.6" /></feComponentTransfer></filter> </svg>#filter);
 filter: brightness(0.6);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.6);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

.hovereffect a,
.hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a,
.hovereffect:hover p,
.hovereffect:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.image-text {

  text-align: justify;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<div class="hovereffect">
<img class="image-style" src="https://www.matheson.com/images/uploads/site-images/MOP-Office-London.jpg" alt="">
<div class="overlay">
  <h2>London</h2>
  <p>
    <a href="#">LINK HERE</a>
  </p>
</div>

</div>
<p class="image-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
<br>More details <a calss="link" href="http://localhost/website/about.html" role="button">about us &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

The padding works but the .image-text css starts behind the image ?

I am not sure if it is me setting this up incorrectly or if you know a better way which will help me.

Below is what I would like the padding to do, but with the images which use the Hover effect.

```css
.image-text {

  text-align: justify;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                      <img class="image-style" src="https://www.matheson.com/images/uploads/site-images/MOP-Office-London.jpg" alt="">
                      <p class="image-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain better **The image code is:** and **my working images code is:**? I am not sure what is the code that you are trying.

Comment: And please, set your code in a snippet.

Comment: It looks like the padding has only worked on the left, right and bottom sides but it is also working for the top side but that padding is starting within the image so it hides the padding on the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a linebreak in the css code:

```
.hovereffect:hover img {
  filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg <-- HERE
```

You cannot have unescaped linebreaks within quotes as it brakes your css.

The solutions are: remove quotes or remove or escape linebreakes.

Working snippet:

```css
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background: #555;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform: scale(0, 1);
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  filter: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filter"> <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.6" /> <feFuncB type="linear" slope="0.6" /></feComponentTransfer></filter> </svg>#filter);
 filter: brightness(0.6);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.6);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

.hovereffect a,
.hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a,
.hovereffect:hover p,
.hovereffect:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="image-style" src="https://www.matheson.com/images/uploads/site-images/MOP-Office-London.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h2>London</h2>
      <p>
        <a href="#">LINK HERE</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <p class="image-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
    <br>More details <a calss="link" href="http://localhost/website/about.html" role="button">about us &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: naaa think thats a different issue possibly. so I didn't add a quite important bit within the css : .image-text {

  text-align: justify;
  padding: 2rem;
}   I for got the padding part as it was within my html file, so when you add this it will look like the padding has only worked on the left, right and bottom sides as the top side starts within the image so it hides the padding on the top.

Answer (score 1):

I think this because `float:left` in hovereffect

#### you can change float by attr left like this

```
.hovereffect {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
background: #555;
}
```

by

```
.hovereffect {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
left : 0;
text-align: center;
cursor: default;
background: #555;
}
```